# Ajax request to Django returns 404 not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am writing my first project in Django where I now want to make an Ajax request using jQuery to get some data. The problem is that the Ajax request returns:

```
 GET http://localhost:8000/ajax/teams_for_issue/?medIssue=MI6 404 (Not Found)
```

I am rather certain that the problem is with the URL, and I have gotten the URLs wrong several times before in this project. My Ajax code looks as follows:

```
var medIssue = _this.issueSelector.val();
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/teams_for_issue/',
    data: {
        'medIssue': medIssue
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        _this.setTeams(data.teams)
    }
});
```

This is the Django function that I want to send the answer:

```
def teams_for_issue(request):
    medIssue = request.GET.get("medIssue", none)
    teams = Team.objects.filter(has_competence=medIssue)
    data = {
        "teams":teams
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I have defined the following URL

```
url(r'newpatient/', views.newpatient, name='newpatient'),
url(r'ajax/teams_for_issue/', views.teams_for_issue, name='teams_for_issue'),
```

Any help on where I go wrong would be much appriciated :)

Comment: Please fix your urls like this ```url(r'^newpatient/$', views.newpatient, name='newpatient'),
url(r'^ajax/teams_for_issue/$', views.teams_for_issue, name='teams_for_issue'),```

Comment: It turned out to be an issue caused by the fact that this is an application with URLs that are supposed to be under the app URL and not directly under the domain URL

Comment: Yes because django use regex to match url and your regex is the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

define type in your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/ajax/teams_for_issue/',
   type: "POST",
   data: {
     'medIssue': medIssue
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
     _this.setTeams(data.teams)
}
});
```

also your view should read data from request.POST

```
def teams_for_issue(request):
    medIssue = request.POST.get("medIssue", none)
    teams = Team.objects.filter(has_competence=medIssue)
    data = {
       "teams":teams
   }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Nope, that does not help. Thanks any way.